# Magento 2: get the current currency code

Tags: magento2, blocks, currency

In Magento 1, you could retrieve the current currency code by doing:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()
```

I'm wondering what is the recommended way of doing it in Magento 2. In my case in a block.

Comment: could you please help me . I have posted a new question (compare store currency & getCurrentCurrency) please check it on my profile .

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### In a block

In Magento 2, you can use the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` which is stored in an accessible variable `$_storeManager` for every class extending `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` so most of the block classes (`Template`, `Messages`, `Redirect` block types but not `Text` nor `TextList`).

This way in your block, you can directly type the following code to get the current currency code:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode()
```

No need to inject the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your construct as it's a variable accessible from any block class.

### In any other class

You can inject the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your constructor:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Then call the same function as the block:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode()
```

Comment: How can I call default currency symbol in phtml page in my custom module?

Comment: This shows EUR instead of €...

Comment: could you please help me . I have posted a new question (compare store currency & getCurrentCurrency) please check it on my profile .

Comment: injecting the storemanager is not always possible, for example when you want to use it in other interfaces, in such cases [using the object manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324844/88201) is an option

Answer (score 7):

This takes inspiration from `Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount` and it's working good in my case (behaving like Magento):

```
protected $_priceCurrency;

public function __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
  ...
)
{           
  $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
  ...
}

/**
 * Get current currency code
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
{
  return $this->_priceCurrency->getCurrency()->getCurrencyCode();
}
```

You can get the currency symbol also:

```
/**
 * Get current currency symbol
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
{
  return $this->_priceCurrency->getCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on the accepted answer if injecting the storemanagerinterface is not an option you can use the objectmanager like this:

```
/**
  5      * Get Store Name
  4      *
  3      * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\StoreManagerInterface
  2      */
  1     protected function getStore() {
123         $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  1         $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
  2         return $storeManager->getStore();
  3     }
```

after which the currency can get fetched with `$this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();`