# Magento 2: How to get current Currency and symbol in PHTML File?

Tags: magento2, template, currency

How can I get current currency and currency symbol in Magento 2 in a template (`.phtml` file)? Without creating a block

Comment: you may refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108012/magento-2-get-the-current-currency-code & http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-currency-code-currency-symbol-currency-rate/

Comment: I have already checked the links both of them created block and used them I dont want to create block

Comment: Use a block. Templates should not contain business logic that should be in blocks or models.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

please note that creating this with objectManager, not the best practice

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currency = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency();
```

getCurrentCurrencyCode()
Gives the Currency code and not the symbol but you were helpful rest I figured -

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
    $currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency(); 
    $currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currencyCode); 
    echo $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol(); ?>
```

Comment: getCurrentCurrencyCode() Gives  the Currency code and not the symbol but you was helpful rest I figured - 
`<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currencyCode);
echo $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
?> `

Comment: Hi Arun, you should post your code as an answer ;)

Comment: Alternative to get the currency symbol: $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();

Answer (score 14):

Another way to approach this would be to use the *Pricing\Helper*, this will both give you the currency symbol and format the number to the correct decimal place.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
$value =  1000; // or whatever value you have in your template
$formattedCurrencyValue = $priceHelper->currency($value, true, false);
```

Although, I believe it's bad practice calling ObjectManager from within a template, for something as simple as getting the correct currency symbol you would imagine it would be more straight forward.

Answer (score 9):

**create helper file with method:**

I believe it's right practice

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;

class Data
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeConfig;

    /**
     * @var CurrencyFactory
     */
    private $currencyCode;

    /**
     * Currency constructor.
     *
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeConfig
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeConfig,
        CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeConfig = $storeConfig;
        $this->currencyCode = $currencyFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSymbol()
    {
        $currentCurrency = $this->storeConfig->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $currency = $this->currencyCode->load($currentCurrency);
        return $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
}
```

**call helper file in phtml**

```
$this->helper('YourNamespace\Modulename\Helper\Data')->getSymbol();
```

Comment: Best Approach,
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce'); 
$currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); 
$currency = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFact‌​ory')->create()->loa‌​d($currencyCode); 
echo $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol(); 
?>
```

Now you will not face the fatal error

Comment: Above code give me below error in phtml page:-  `Class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce does not exist`

Comment: The `StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce ` contain **Non-ASCII characters**, so it has the `Class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterfa‌​ce does not exist` error, we need rewrite it to `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`. It is difficult to see the difference by eyes. @PurushotamSharma

Answer (score 2):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currency = $currencysymbol->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currency);
$currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct(
 ...
 \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
 ... )
     {
    ...
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getCurrencySymbol() {
        return $this ->_storeManager-> getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that some of the answers above includes code with invisible characters (&#8203 and &#8204, in particular) that makes it unusable. I haven't tried all versions of the code that has been posted here, since many have posted the same code. But here comes a clean code, with no invisible characters.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currencyFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory');
$currencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$currency = $currencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCode);
$currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```

Answer (score -3):

A shorter version that should work:

```
<?php 
    echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); 
?>
```

Comment: The requirement is for Magento-2 version. Your code belongs to Magento-1.