# Magento 2 change the addtocart button text on detail page based on the product increment

Tags: magento2, addtocart, knockoutjs

I am doing customisation on PDP page as per my client requirement, For my requirement i am using the grouped product, also added a option to increase/decrease each product quantity count, when increase or decrease a product quantity need to change the "addtocart" button based on the quantity and the each item price.

Example:
One group product has 3 mapped product, each simple product price is $200, so when i added one quantity on each the item, then the "addtocart" button text need to change "Add 3 items to Basket($600.00), if i decrease so need to change the addtocart button text.

Kindly check the attached screen and share your idea.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need three things to achieve this

1. I hope you added the **Increment/Decrement** button by overriding **Magento_GroupedProduct::product/view/type/grouped.phtml** in which please add `data-item-price="<?= /* @noEscape */ ($_item->getFinalPrice()) ?>"` line in QTY Input as shown below.[image]
2. Pass the currency Symbol while initiating JS. (References [How to get current Currency and symbol in PHTML File?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130391/magento-2-how-to-get-current-currency-and-symbol-in-phtml-file) or [Get current currency symbol in Magento2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349247/get-current-currency-symbol-in-magento2))[image]
3. In the increment decrement method in JS, at last line of each method, call one custom method such as `self.updateItemsAndPrice();`. In that custom method, add below code[image]

```
updateItemsAndPrice: function () {
                    let self = this;
                    let totalSelectedItemsCount = 0;
                    let totalSelectedItemPrice = 0;
        
                    $('.input-text-qty').each(function () {
                        let qty = $(this).val();
                        if (qty > 0) {
                            totalSelectedItemsCount++;
                            totalSelectedItemPrice += (qty * parseInt($(this).attr('data-item-price')));
                        }
                    })
        
                    if (totalSelectedItemsCount > 0) {
                        $('#product-addtocart-button > span').text("Add " + totalSelectedItemsCount + " item(s) to Basket (" + self.options.currency_symbol + totalSelectedItemPrice + ")");
                    } else {
                        $('#product-addtocart-button > span').text("Add to Cart");
                    }
                }
```