# Magento 2. Change the price format .0000 to .00

Tags: magento2, phtml, final-price.phtml

In abandoned cart email I have

```
<?= $item->getPriceInclTax() ?>
```

and it looks like this

> 29.0000

Is it possible to change to

> 29.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **number_format** function

```
<?= number_format($item->getPriceInclTax(), 2) ?>
```

Comment: Perfectly. Thank you for help. Do you know how to add a currency symbol?

Comment: Check this solution to add currency symbol https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130391/magento-2-how-to-get-current-currency-and-symbol-in-phtml-file