# How to get store currency code by store Id in Magento 2.3.x?

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-id

I have multiple stores on my website. I need to get the store currency code by store Id. How can I get it?

I was trying by below code but it's always returning default store currency code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');       
$storeCurrencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

Thanks for your cooperation.

**[Update with Solution]**

I have got the solution after reviewing Magento core code. My solution code below:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

// Return Default Store Currency Code
$defaultCurrencyCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

// Return Specific Store Currency Code
$storeId = 1; // it can be any store id     
$storeCurrencyCode = $storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108012/magento-2-get-the-current-currency-code

Comment: @MohitPatel didn't find anything to get currency code by store id

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create a block to get currency code and pass to template. Please do not directly use the object manager in code.

> Default Store Currency data: Code, Rate, Symbol.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class DefaultStoreCurrencyBlock extends Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getBaseCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }    

    public function getDefaultCurrencyCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getDefaultCurrencyCode();
    }

    public function getAllowedCurrencies()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getAllowedCurrencies();
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrencyRate()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
    {
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }    
}
?>
```

> Specific Store Currency Code: Code, Rate, Symbol.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class SpecificStoreCurrencyBlock extends Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currency = $currency;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function CurrentStoreID()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
    }

    public function getBaseCurrencyCode()
    {  
        $storeId = $this->CurrentStoreID();
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
    {
        $storeId = $this->CurrentStoreID();
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }    

    public function getDefaultCurrencyCode()
    {
        $storeId = $this->CurrentStoreID();
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getDefaultCurrencyCode();
    }

    public function getAllowedCurrencies()
    {
        $storeId = $this->CurrentStoreID();
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getAllowedCurrencies();
    }

    public function getCurrentCurrencyRate()
    {
        $storeId = $this->CurrentStoreID();
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCurrentCurrencyRate();
    }

}
?>
```

Get the output of the currency data in phtml file

```
echo $block->getCurrentCurrencySymbol() . '<br />';
echo $block->getCurrentCurrencyCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getBaseCurrencyCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getDefaultCurrencyCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getCurrentCurrencyRate() . '<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't need it in the template. I needed it in the Cron file where I was importing products programmatically from third-party API.

Comment: you can also use above code in cron file

Comment: How to pass store id dynamically in corn file using your solution?  where this function using to get store id:  `public function CurrentStoreID()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In *Magento2.3*, we can use below code to get currency symbol.

```
<?php

class CurrencyCode
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    private $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    
    /**
     * Get current store currency symbol
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrencySymbol()
    {
        $storeId = 1;
        $currencySymbol = $this->priceCurrency->getCurrencySymbol($storeId);
        return $currencySymbol;
    }
}
```